# How to extract NuGet contentFiles to a specific directory?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

### What I've tried so far:

I've got the following .nuspec file, defining my package (simplified for better readability):

```xml
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
  .
  .
  .
    <dependencies/>
    <contentFiles>     
      <files include="any\any\config\*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Assembly.dll" target="lib\net461" />
    <file src="bin\Assembly.pdb" target="lib\net461" />
    <file src="Config\cf.xml" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
    <file src="Config\cf.txt" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

As you can see, it contains a *compiled Assembly* along with it's *debug symbols file* as well as two *content Files* in a sub directory.

This results in the following compilation output, where the *Assembly.dll* is extracted to the output directory as well as the *config* sub directory (with the two cf.* files in it):

[image: actual build output]

---

### Question:

What I want to do is to move the sub directory *config* one step up in the directory tree, so it sits *next* to the output directory - basically maintaining the structure of the file input in the .nuspec file (assuming *bin* is the output directory of my .csproj):

[image: nuspec directory structure]   [image: desired build output]

**How can I tell the NuGet package the exact location where I want the contentFiles to be extracted to?**

Comment: But `src` is a source/input for nuspec ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#file-element-attributes ). To move `config` folder you probably need to update `.csproj` file not a `nuspec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a MSBuild target that moves your `config` folder one level above the project build output.

Add a `.targets` file with the following content to your NuGet's `build\net461` folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- Sets up items for target MoveConfigFiles, so that they can be used as Inputs and Outputs. -->
  <Target Name="PrepareMoveConfigFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- ItemGroup wrapped in Target to delay evaluation of contained Items -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Contains source locations of files to be moved -->
      <ConfigSourceFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\config\**\*.*" />
      <!-- Contains target locations of files to be moved -->
      <ConfigTargetFiles Include="@(ConfigSourceFiles->'%(FullPath)'->Replace('\config\', '\..\config\'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- Moves files from $(OutputPath)\config to $(OutputPath)\..\config,
       then deletes $(OutputPath)\config. -->
  <Target Name="MoveConfigFiles" AfterTargets="PrepareMoveConfigAndSqlFiles" Inputs="@(ConfigSourceFiles)" Outputs="@(ConfigTargetFiles)">
    <Move SourceFiles="@(ConfigSourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ConfigTargetFiles)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)\config" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The target `PrepareMoveConfigFiles` is executed after the `Build` target (which guarantees the NuGet's contents exist in build output), and sets up items used as `Inputs` and `Outputs` of the next `MoveConfigFiles` target. (The items are set inside this target to ensure they are evaluated after the `Build` target has completed. If the item definitions would be placed below the `Project` level, they would be evaluated earlier and thus would potentially be empty because the files of the `content` folder have not yet been deployed.)

The `ConfigSourceFiles` item just contains the source files, and `ConfigTargetFiles` takes the paths of all `ConfigSourceFiles` and replaces `\config\` with `\..\config\`, which leads to the desired target locations.

The `MoveConfigFiles` target then uses the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/move-task) and [RemoveDir](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/removedir-task) tasks to accomplish the movement of files and deletion of the original `config` folder.

Comment: Disclaimer: Made possible after extending my MSBuild knowledge by watching the great [MSBuild webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ew5Yo2utdtk) [@martin-ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784387/) gave on YouTube. Many thanks for that!

As I'm new to MSBuild, suggestions are highly welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird question...

You have several things to do a nuspec file;

The main are "the nuget packages". 
Your nuspec line:

```
<file src="bin\Assembly.dll" target="lib\net461" />
<file src="bin\Assembly.pdb" target="lib\net461" />
```

I don't understand Assembly.pdb to distribute it, but is not important.

The goal of  this lines are distribute yout dlls in your projects.
When you compile your solution (in your solution dir) it search for this dlls in same root application directory or else check if are register on system (gac mainly).

On the other hand other kind of lines are the "content" into nuget

```
<file src="Config\cf.xml" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
<file src="Config\cf.txt" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
```

This is additional content but maybe it may not will be used in the project.

If you want a route system you can use content, but you could have problems using the dlls.

So, I suppose that maybe you would this:

```
    <file src="bin\Assembly.dll" target="contentFiles\any\any\bin" />
    <file src="bin\Assembly.pdb" target="contentFiles\any\any\bin" />
    <file src="Config\cf.xml" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
    <file src="Config\cf.txt" target="contentFiles\any\any\config"/>
```

And other nuspec example (I would not do this, but, it is possible to do it):

```
<files>
    <file src="content\bin\youtBinayFile" target="content\bin\youtBinayFile" />
    <file src="content\Config\YourConfigFile" target="content\Config\YourConfigFile" />
    <file src="readme.txt" target="readme.txt" />
</files>
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want. I want:
1. To have my `Assembly.dll` from my NuGet package extracted into the build output. This is already working.
2. To have the `config` folder and its contents extracted one level _above_ the build output. This is not working at the moment. Instead, `config` is created inside the build output.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that's possible. Because the output compilation directory is not in the nuget package. You could modify it's csproj ($OutputPath). As @Renat said...